# Mule 4 : Dataweave : How to filter, and update a matched object in a list?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Scenario : I have a list of Students. I want to filter a student having a specific studentId and update its Marks to say 60 in the list. How can I do that **without using the "update" operator introduced in Mule 4.3**

Student list:

```
[
  {
    "studentId": "781e5dc2-f76b-4e35-ac27-f5835c960083",
    "studentName": "Mr. 1",
    "studentMarks": 1
  },
  {
    "studentId": "cb8a606a-b91c-4697-8d73-84170b156180",
    "studentName": "Mr. 2",
    "studentMarks": 4
  },
  {
    "studentId": "656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79",
    "studentName": "Mr. 3",
    "studentMarks": 9
  },
  {
    "studentId": "d1cd5ee3-cef6-4d5e-a380-cb5e79495f77",
    "studentName": "Mr. 4",
    "studentMarks": 16
  }
]
```

Student whose marks is to be updated to 60 is with studentId : 656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79

So After the update the final result should be  :

```
[
  {
    "studentId": "781e5dc2-f76b-4e35-ac27-f5835c960083",
    "studentName": "Mr. 1",
    "studentMarks": 1
  },
  {
    "studentId": "cb8a606a-b91c-4697-8d73-84170b156180",
    "studentName": "Mr. 2",
    "studentMarks": 4
  },
  **{
    "studentId": "656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79",
    "studentName": "Mr. 3",
    "studentMarks": 60
  }**,
  {
    "studentId": "d1cd5ee3-cef6-4d5e-a380-cb5e79495f77",
    "studentName": "Mr. 4",
    "studentMarks": 16
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the update operator was added in Mule 4.3 there is an [update() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-values-functions-update) in the Values package since Mule 4.2.

I recommend to avoid fixing the id so I'll encapsulate the change in a function to parametrize it:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values

fun updateStudentMarks(list, id) =
    list map 
        if ($.studentId == id) $ update "studentMarks" with 60 
        else $

---
updateStudentMarks(payload, "656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79")
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this DW. No **update** operator used. Only condidtional logic. If you have any dynamic kind-of requirement and no hard-coding please let me know, I will try to update my answer.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map (($ - 'studentMarks') ++
{'studentMarks': 
    if ($."studentId" == "656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79")
        60
    else
        $.'studentMarks'
})
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "studentId": "781e5dc2-f76b-4e35-ac27-f5835c960083",
    "studentName": "Mr. 1",
    "studentMarks": 1
  },
  {
    "studentId": "cb8a606a-b91c-4697-8d73-84170b156180",
    "studentName": "Mr. 2",
    "studentMarks": 4
  },
  {
    "studentId": "656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79",
    "studentName": "Mr. 3",
    "studentMarks": 60
  },
  {
    "studentId": "d1cd5ee3-cef6-4d5e-a380-cb5e79495f77",
    "studentName": "Mr. 4",
    "studentMarks": 16
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain the syntax and how did you come up with it?

Comment: @BibekKr.Bazaz Since  ($ - 'studentMarks')  is inside map , it will remove all studentMarks field from original payload .Now manually I am checking if ID matches required ID then append (++) "studentMarks" to 60 to original payload where ID matches else $.'studentMarks' (the original marks)

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload filter ($.studentId !='656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79')) ++ (payload filter ($.studentId=='656b247f-a755-476f-a845-b61d28e4be79') map {
    "studentId": $.studentId,
    "studentName": $.studentName,
    "studentMarks": 60
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).